# Firefox REST Client group/save requests into projects

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, rest-client

Is there a way for all the requests I save to group them per folder/project on the Firefox REST Client extension? At the moment when I save each request is listed with all previous saved requests, so trying to keep them a little bit more tidy, like you can do with Postmand

Answer (score 0):

There are other extensions for Firefox that permit to organize your requests in groups or folder.

There is [Resting](http://resting.owlcode.eu)

[image]

or [Rester](https://github.com/frigus02/RESTer) for example

Disclaimer: I'm the creator and maintainer of Resting

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy. You have multiple such answers, so please disclose affiliation in *all* of them.